# Is there a way to find max cpu size from a Prometheus query.?

Tags: prometheus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyII2.png)

Below is the query to get cpu usage(blue color)

```
  sum(
    1 - sum without (mode) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=~"idle|iowait|steal"}[2m]))
    *
    on(instance) group_left() (
      label_replace(max by (node) (kube_node_role{role=~"worker|master"}), "instance", "$1", "node","(.*)")
    )
  )
```

below is the query to get max cpu request

```
  sum(
    kube_pod_resource_request{resource="cpu"}
    *
    on(node) group_left(role) (
      max by (node) (kube_node_role{role=~"worker|master"})
    )
  )
```

How to get full CPU capacity ?

How to get full CPU capacity ?